# Google RE2 library cannot compile with 'make testinstall' in ubuntu

Tags: c++, compilation, re2

Gurus!

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit to compile latest Google RE2 library, but 'make testinstall' failed to compile, here is the log:

kevin@ubuntu:~/re2$ make testinstall

cp testinstall.cc obj
(cd obj && g++ -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib testinstall.cc -lre2 -pthread -o testinstall)
/tmp/ccSsaSXS.o: In function `main':
testinstall.cc:(.text+0xce): undefined reference to`re2::FilteredRE2::FirstMatch(re2::StringPiece const&, std::vector > const&) const'
/usr/local/lib/libre2.so: undefined reference to `pthread_rwlock_rdlock'
/usr/local/lib/libre2.so: undefined reference to`pthread_rwlock_wrlock'
/usr/local/lib/libre2.so: undefined reference to `pthread_rwlock_destroy'
/usr/local/lib/libre2.so: undefined reference to`pthread_rwlock_init'
/usr/local/lib/libre2.so: undefined reference to `pthread_rwlock_unlock'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [testinstall] Error 1

I tried to replace -pthread with -lpthread, still failed, then I dumped libre2.so and found that pthread_xxx is in it.
  Here is the issue tracking in RE2 forum: https://code.google.com/p/re2/issues/detail?id=100

Anyone here have ever complied RE2 successfully ? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

See [this comment](https://code.google.com/p/re2/issues/detail?id=100):

> Adding -pthread to LDFLAGS seems to fix `make test` (all tests are
>   passing), but not `make testinstall`.

That will get you to the next error

Comment: Yes, if i change nothing, both 'make test' and 'make testinstall' will fail. Until now, I could not find a way to get all build passed:

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you build it for 'make testinstall' might not be necessary.
I just needed to get python re2 port working, and this can be installed after running make install.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter this problem before. Modify the makefile and use -lpthread instead of -pthread.

Answer (score 0):

So I tried looking for the lines in testinstall.cc that were causing the symbol errors and I found out that the only line was on line 18:

18 - f.firstMatch(:abbccc:, ids);

I commented this line out (so that the FullMatch function below is still called) and just ran g++ testinstall.cc -lre2 -pthread -o testinstall (basically what the Makefile does) and I was able to get a binary successfully. Although this might not really solve the problem, its good to know that we can still use the RE2::Fullmatch and partial match functions

If I were to guess, maybe there is a dependency somewhere inside the filtered_re2 module?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. But if you compile with `-static` everything goes well.

`nm -C` shows that the "missing" symbol exists in both `.a` and `.so` files.